# Students hate me

Tags: online-presence

I have recently started my job at a university. For students I appeared as a strict teacher who ask for a daily response. I followed the each teaching strategy of my highly intelligent and one of favoirite teacher among students. The class that I was assigned, is one of the favoirite class of head of the department, some students are very near to him.
The class has no base or background about subject so in start they felt difficulty in understanding things. And told me that they are not getting my lectures because I am fast at speaking.
I sent my lectures recording to my friend (he has 10 years of experiemce) and asked him aboit lecture quality or speed. And he said that everything is good and understandable.
I, then tried to slow my speed of speaking and taught them basics (which were expected as prerequisite of course), told them each thing, which according to them I am going in deep of the topic.
Then they complained I am speaking fast and teaching topic in depth.
Then I contacted a teacher (in the same department from other campus) and asked about his teachings strategy materials. He told me that he is tecahing the topics in same manner.

Then student continuously said that they are unable to understand my lectures. I asked my colleague to talk to them. Ahe talked to students and told me that don't force students to learn. If four students are responsing means my lecture is understandable (among whole class 4 to 5 students were alwayz responding to me).
So continue teaching as you are teaching.

So I followed his advice not completely but to some extent. Now they all are happy because I am not asking for their response but they didn't stop insulting.

Comment: maybe a better fit for https://academia.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I can't help you, but I just wanted to say it's great that you actually care and wish to improve. Teaching is a learned skill, and so many knowledgable people are awful educators but refuse to accept it. I think even acknowledging it puts you in a great position

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/152135/how-to-handle-students-disrespectfulness sorry, i forgot the link: this is the question (and more by the same user) that may help you.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Not everywhere in the world. In my university, my profs and I (as a phd student and later in another university as a lecturer) did not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the interactions described here are specific to academia, not to a workplace. As suggested, it might be better on Academia SE.

Comment: Step 1 is to establish who "they" are. When I give a talk, there are always a few who feel it was too simple and introductory, **and** and a few who feel it was to advanced and complicated. You cannot achieve "nobody thinks I am teaching at the wrong pace". Wanting to improve is great; changing your course every week on the fly in response to a few complaints is not only hard on you, it's hard on the other students who were not complaining.

Comment: As for speaking too quickly, a good rule of thumb I was taught for public speaking / presenting is to speak 1,5 to 2 times more slowly than you normally would, depending on your usual speaking speed. This has the added benefit of helping you to be more conscious of your words as well as giving you the time to consider which words should come next.

Comment: Just a left-field guess, but is it possible that you have an accent some students have difficulty understanding, (and perhaps they aren't sure how to raise this to you without being offensive/rude)?  Or maybe some students have difficulty understanding the language you're teaching in?  Or technical difficulties with either your recording tech or their listening tech (if teaching online)? If you aren't talking too fast but still get asked to slow down, I suspect there is some other barrier to understanding and 'slow down' is their attempt at a solution.

Comment: I speak in their native language. Whixh they speak ta home. I have asked my friends(who have tecahing experiemce) about my speaking speed while teaching. According to them speed is okay. And I usually repeat each sentance.

Answer (score 4):

Teaching customs, and student expectations, differ greatly from country to country, and from campus to campus. It depends *a lot* on where you are.

For example, in math classes in the United States, it is not typical that you can call on the class and expect students to answer. This goes especially if you have a particular answer in mind, which you hope the students will give. It is not that students are lazy, but rather that social customs go against it.

Your desire to improve is commendable! I'd recommend seeking out other professors, possibly in different departments, but *at the same university*. Your university might have a "Center for Teaching Excellence" or something similar; if so, make an appointment, talk to somebody, and listen to their advice.

Overall, you might not be able to recreate the atmosphere in which you yourself thrived. Think about your goals as an educator, and try to understand the constraints in which you are operating -- and you can look forward to improvement and success.

Comment: What exactly are these social customs you speak of

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly some things you can do, you can ask students for feedback in an informal teacher evaluation. With open questions you can get some clues as to what part of your teaching might be causing issues.

Another solution is to film yourself teaching. This way instead of telling how you are doing things you can evaluate yourself and have other evaluate how you teach.With this in mind you can then compare to others and see what might be improved, though this requires to take a step back and be objective about yourself.

Going by your own point of view when talking about your teaching method is highly biased and never tells the whole story.

There is also a possibility that the students are not familiar with your approach or have a personnal stake against you. But the latter should only be considered as the last option on the list.

Hope this helps.